# SDL WorldServer 10.2.1 - how to configure W3C ITS Compliant XML Studio File Type filter

Tags: tridion-worldserver

We are using SDL WorldServer 10.2.1 and Tridion 2011. (Windows Server 2003/Tomcat 6.0/SQL Server 2008 R2) Recently the Tridion folks asked me to ensure that the appropriate filters (Management | Linguistic Tool Setup | Filter Configurations) were installed and configured to allow dynamic values to be used from Tridion.

So the appropriate filter (Text Studio File Type) is installed and configured for WS for what Tridion wants to do. The following inline tags are  added:

```
{.+}

~.+?~
```

So for example, when a new project is created and uploaded file source is:

```
Hello~test~my~test~name~test~is~test~Robert

Hello^{thing.thing}World
```

The result in Browser Workbench is:

```
{1}{2}{3}{4}

{5}
```

While this is exactly what is desired, it is only working in WS. While Tridion is able to connect and create projects in WS, they are not able to get the same result using the same source file. It is reported that the filter "W3C ITS Compliant XML Studio File Type" should be configured. Would someone be kind enough to assist with the configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the task of processing special fields and creating placeholders in WorldServer for a file sent from a Tridion server, the file will need to be processed by the WorldServer “W3C ITS Compliant XML Studio File Type” (W3C filter) filter.  However the W3C filter expects to find its processing instructions in the Tridion file itself. So to process special fields and create placeholders, add the placeholder instructions within the Tridion file.